# Which arptables rules to avoid man-in-the-middle attack?

Tags: networking, security, arp

One strategy to stop a man-in-the-middle attacker is to restrict accepted ARPs packet to only those need to the router.

**What are the `arptables` rules to restrict accepted ARPs to only my router with known MAC?**

The ARP packet generated with the following command from the attacker machine have all to be dropped:

```
arpspoof -i wlan0  -t <Victim IP (me) > < gateway IP >
```

PS: I am aware that IGMP can also be used to route the packet to the attacker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Block ARP traffic from and to all machines (default: DENY)
arptables -P INPUT DROP
arptables -P OUTPUT DROP

# Allow router (fixed ARP)
arptables -A INPUT --source-mac <ROUTER_MAC> --destination-mac <USER MAC> -j ACCEPT
```

where `<ROUTER_MAC>` is the mac of the subnet router.

Comment: what about arptables LOG?

Comment: I don't think setting these rules is the proper way. ARP packets are sent to destination mac, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff. Also if your machine needs to accept packets from outside of your local network and the router doesn't know your mac, it will issue an ARP request which will be accepted by your rules but the ARP response will be blocked because output chain has no rule and default policy is DROP. I think you can create a static MAC entry and disable ARP completely on the interface.